# how jsp:forward didn't find specified html page which is not in the same directory or not in application but finds Other

Tags: java, html, jsp

i have index.jsp which is defined under welcome-file-list tag. here it goes

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Index </title>
</head>
<body>

<jsp:forward page="contacts.html"></jsp:forward>
<a href="hello.html">Say Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

it has a forward action now the request is forwarded to contacts.html but in my application there is no contacts.html page under any directory but has a page contact.jsp under web-inf folder. when i run my application as a default it goes to welcome file page and now that it is forwarded to contacts.html page and since i don't have contacts.html it must show me an error right? but instead it is showing me contact.jsp page which is in web-inf folder.

there is an image which gives the picture of application structure give the presence of index.jsp page and contact.jsp page. which i can't post here due my reputation.

web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: please edit the question and post the web.xml file

Comment: Where is your image ? Please kindly edit your question.

Comment: @Kalathoki i said my reputation is not allowing me to post images.

Comment: @kiran See `![enter image description here][1]` you missed to enter image description so it is not displaying.

Comment: @fmodos yes edited with web.xml file contents

Comment: @Kalathoki its been saying that i need a reputaion of 10 to add an image